# Best default header name?

Tags: c++, header

I have a question about best C++ coding practices. I noticed that for almost all applications the first/main .cpp file is "main.cpp". My question is simple, what is best practice for naming the first/main .h file? "main.h"?

Comment: What is the "first" header file?  Call it whatever makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, the declarations needed for `xxx.cpp` go in `xxx.h` or `xxx.hpp`. So in your case it would be `main.h`.

However, you should name it with whatever makes sense.

Most of the time, your `main.cpp` won't do much, because it would use various classes. Each class will probably go in `ClassName.cpp` (although not necessarily). So you may not need a `main.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I always use main.h...Its the most common, or sometimes i use something more exact like structures.h or MyFunctions.h or something like that